# AWS create bucket XML confusion

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services

"docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateBucket.html" here is said to use this XML:

```
<CreateBucketConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <LocationConstraint>string</LocationConstraint>
</CreateBucketConfiguration>
```

when requesting to create bucket but I can not understand very well one moment,when I send request why do I need to send this XML as well and what role is playing "s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01". I know that XML is used to send data,I read also about namespace in XML(xmlns),I read also about URI and URL. Separately I understand idea of these things,but when I wrote code to create request I am losing the idea,I can not understand what is happening actually(behind the scene).

here is part from whole code,function to create bucket

```
import requests
import requests_aws4auth as aws4auth
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import mimetypes
access_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_key = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
region = 'eu-central-1'
endpoint = 's3.{}.amazonaws.com'.format(region)
auth = aws4auth.AWS4Auth(access_id, access_key, region, 's3')
ns = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/'
def create_bucket(bucket):
    XML = ET.Element('CreateBucketConfiguration')
    XML.attrib['xmlns'] = ns
    location = ET.SubElement(XML, 'LocationConstraint')
    location.text = auth.region
    data = ET.tostring(XML, encoding='utf-8')
    url = 'http://{}.{}'.format(bucket, endpoint)
    r = requests.put(url, data=data, auth=auth)
    if r.ok:
        print('{} bucket created'.format(bucket))
```

Here the moment I can not understand very well is "r = requests.put(url, data=data, auth=auth)" specifically data part.data is containing that XML.Shortly to ask what this XML is doing in this request?

Can somebody give me brief clarification about my confusion.I would be thankful.

Comment: Are you unable to use the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/)?

Comment: How about using boto3? `import boto3
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
s3.create_bucket(Bucket="mybucket", ....) `